# python: The comparison of numbers stored as elements in an array gives incorrect result

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numeric, comparison-operators

I am brand new to python and am trying to write a script that iterates over a list created by parsing a simple tab delineated file then comparing values in that list.

The input file looks like this:

```
1   11  12
9   46  200
471 56  30
```

And the code is:

```
with open("my_file.txt", "r") as my_file:
    str = my_file.read()

    clnstr = str.replace('\n', '\t')


content_list = clnstr.split("\t")

for i in range(0, len(content_list)-3, 3 ):
    
    if (content_list[i+1] >= content_list[i]):
        
        print(content_list[i], "is smaller than", content_list[i+1]) 

    else :
        print(content_list[i], "is bigger than", content_list[i+1])
```

However the output of these comparisons is wrong for some of the values:

```
1 is smaller than 11
9 is bigger than 46
471 is smaller than 56
```

I think its because its only comparing the first digits of the numbers stored in the array? If so how do i fix this in the above code?

Comment: You are getting "alphabetical" sort because you are not converting your values to integers.  Try converting to `int()` each of the items before comparing.  Recall (or learn...:) ) that everything python reads from file or from keyboard input comes in as a *string*.

Comment: Excellent! many thanks. I thought it was something basic like that I hadn't learned.